# How do you write a unit test to test an ASP.NET web forms application for CSRF vulnerability?

Tags: asp.net, security, unit-testing

We have an ASP.NET web forms application that is probably vulnerable to Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack. How do we begin to write a unit test that will alert us to this? Using NUnit. Some tips or pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how CSRF is done. Get into the hackers way of thinking. You then need to create automated tests performing CSRF. This will probably not be a unit test (testing a single unit), more like an integration test. When you have succeeded in performing the CSRF attack - when your tests are red - you'll be able to fix the problem.

Check out the [CSRF FAQ](http://www.cgisecurity.com/csrf-faq.html) for more information on how to perform the attack. And here's a good wiki article about [Testing for CSRF](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_CSRF_(OWASP-SM-005)) you should check out.

Answer (score 1):

CSRF is an attack where a user is tricked (by a link in an email for example) to perform an action on attacker's behalf,  while being already authenticated on your website .

There are several ways to reduce the risk which you should test for -

- GET requests should not have side-effects - all actions should be done using POST requests only. It's more difficult for an attacker to generate a POST request originating from the user.
- You want to have a  random unique per-page string sent to the user and checked on return to the server. The user's cookie will be sent in a request caused by the attacker, but the attacker will not know the string stored in the form. In .NET, I think you can use Viewstate for this.
- For especially sensitive (or attack prone) actions or after some period of inactivity, you may request repeat authentication by the user

[OWASP](http://www.owasp.org) (linked by Torbjørn) is indeed an excellent resource and contains much more detailed explanation and advice.